# List of Contacts from Contacts App in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swiftui, cncontactpicker, contactsui

Hi I am trying to build an interface that lists all the contacts just like the `Contacts` and `Phone` app with the same `UI`. What I have tried so far is below. Basically I tried to implement `CNContactPickerViewController` from `ContactsUI` using the `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. However what I am getting is a blank white page.

```
struct ContactsViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ContactsViewController>) -> CNContactPickerViewController {
        let controller = CNContactPickerViewController()
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        controller.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactGivenNameKey]
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CNContactPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ContactsViewController>) {
        print("updating")
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, CNContactPickerDelegate {
        var parent: ContactsViewController

        init(_ contactsViewController: ContactsViewController) {
            self.parent = contactsViewController
        }

    }
}
```

And the SwiftUI file;

```
struct ContactsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ContactsViewController()
    }
}
```

A reminder is I am calling the `ContactsView` inside of `TabView` in some other `SwiftUI` file.  So I want show contacts in a `SwiftUI` `View` that is part of `TabView`. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57621666/8818408

(1) works but flashes a view before showing the list of contacts.  Not a good experience for the user.

(2) sort of works.  It also flashes a view before showing the list of contacts.  It shows with unexpected transparency and unexpected colors along leading, trailing, and bottom edges.  These may be possible to sort out.

I'm just getting started trying to resolve issues with #2 above.  If anyone can offer a solution that works completely, that would be great.[image: Screen shot of #2]