# Tab works, but can't select TextFields using touch in iOs

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

I have an app I've been working on for a while that is all SwiftUI and runs on macOS, iOS, and iPadOS.  One feature is a simple address lookup that allows the user to either enter an address or do a search in their Contacts app.  The problem is, while a search works fine, and if you have a keyboard, you can hit tab and enter a first name, etc. going between fields in the SwiftUI view, you cannot use any pointer to select any fields on in the view.  The following code is the Swift View.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        GeometryReader { geomtry in
            VStack {
                TextField("Address Line 1", text: $addressLine1)
                    .customTextField()
                Spacer()
            }
            ContactPicker(showPicker: $showPicker, onSelectContact: {contact in
                firstName = contact.givenName
                lastName = contact.familyName
                if contact.postalAddresses.count > 0 {
                    if let addressString = (
                        ((contact.postalAddresses[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "labelValuePair")
                            as AnyObject).value(forKey: "value"))
                        as? CNPostalAddress {
                        // swiftlint:disable:next line_length
                        let mailAddress = CNPostalAddressFormatter.string(from: addressString, style: .mailingAddress)
                        addressLine1 = "\(addressString.street)"
                    }
                }
                self.showPicker.toggle()
            }, onCancel: nil)
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10 )
        .navigationTitle("Recipient")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                HStack {
                                    Button(action: {
                                            self.showPicker.toggle()
                                    }, label: {
                                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                                    })
                                }
        )
    }
}
```

`
I have confirmed that if I disable the ContactPicker function the screen allows me to select fields.. so it must be caused by the ShowPicker capabilities.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I've been using the code represented here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246685/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable-and-cncontactpickerviewcontroller/57621666#57621666 as created by @youjinp, The code above has been refactored to be minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was none intuitive but I have resolved the issue.  From what I can tell, the sequence of the ContactPicker and the VStack are important.  By moving the ContactPicker to the top of the View, the issue has been resolved.